# Removable HDD Format

Tags: partitioning

I am just wondering which type of partitioning I should choose for installing a Linux distro in a USB hard drive.

I want to have partitions for /, /usr, and physical memory.

Which of them should be primary partitions and which of them should be logical?

Comment: Define "physical memory".  This term normally refers to RAM, which has nothing to do with hard drives.

Answer (score 2):

If you boot the Live Media in your computer and have the USB Hard Drive installed (plugged in) you will be given a choice during installation as to WHERE to install and WHAT format you want.

I choose EXT4 because its more versatile than the other formats. Personal preference.

use [THIS GUIDE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) and you shouldn't have any issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With four or less partitions there should not be a problem making them all primary.

Have you considered also making a swap partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 4 primary partitions, so if you want more then 4 partitions you will have to use extended/logical partitions. Other then that limit (4 primary partitions) it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

As already posted, with an MSDOS partition table (the default) you can have up to four primary partitions, so just make *every* partition a primary partition.

I'm not sure why you'd want `/usr/` on a separate partition. `/usr/` contains "userspace program files" - it's the equivalent of `C:\Program Files\` on a Windows machine.

I think what you're trying to do is put your personal files (Windows `C:\Users\` or `C:\Documents and Settings\`) on a separate partition. This corresponds to `/home/` in Linux.

And by "physical memory" I think you mean a swap partition. A swap partition on a USB hard disk is going to be doggedly slow, but if you have enough RAM you won't be hitting swap too much (so no big deal.)